# Migrate hive table to Google BigQuery

Tags: hadoop, hive, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to design a sort of data pipeline to migrate my Hive tables into BigQuery. Hive is running on an Hadoop on premise cluster. This is my current design, actually, it is very easy, it is just a shell script:

for each table source_hive_table {

- INSERT overwrite table `target_avro_hive_table` `SELECT * FROM source_hive_table;`
- Move the resulting avro files into google cloud storage using `distcp`
- Create first BQ table: `bq load --source_format=AVRO your_dataset.something something.avro`
- Handle any casting issue from BigQuery itself, so selecting from the table just written and handling manually any casting

}

Do you think it makes sense? Is there any better way, perhaps using Spark?
I am not happy about the way I am handling the casting, I would like to avoid creating the BigQuery table twice.

Comment: The best/easiest way to migratre from any other DB to BigQuery, is to export (e.g. CSV), upload to GCS and import. Done.

Comment: is this just one time migration ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your migration logic makes sense.

I personally prefer to do the CAST for specific types directly into the initial "Hive query" that generates your Avro (Hive) data. For instance, "*decimal*" type in Hive maps to the Avro 'type': *"type":"bytes","logicalType":"decimal","precision":10,"scale":2*

And BQ will just take the primary type (here "bytes") instead of the logicalType.
So that is why I find it easier to cast directly in Hive (here to "double").
Same problem happens to the date-hive type.

Comment: Can you elaborate the 'CAST into the initial Hive Query'?
My problem is, for example, the mapping between Avro timestamp to BQ timestamp.

Comment: Here is an example of Hive query I execute. You can see here 2 cast:

`CREATE TABLE sluangsay.xxxx
STORED AS AVRO AS
select
    cast( itemordervalue as double),
    hit_time_gmt,
    cast( datedir as string),
    post_cookies
from tst_bidwh.xxx_source where datedir = '2017-03-24';`