# Move data from hive tables in Google Dataproc to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

We are doing the data transformations using Google Dataproc and all our data is residing in Dataproc Hive tables. How do i transfer/move this data to BigQuery.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so it's easier to help you. Have you tried something so far? Do you have any code? Are you seeing any traceback error? The more information you give the more likely you are to get help.

Comment: We are in the process of evaluating the GCP cloud offerings. Our use case is to use Dataproc for our Hive/Spark related jobs and dump final data from Hive tables to BigQuery. We see that Google is offering Bigquery connector to transfer data from Hive to BigQuery, i just wanted to check what would be the ideal way of moving the data from Dataproc to BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer to BigQuery from Hive seems to have a standard pattern:

- dump your Hive into Avro files
- Load those files in BigQuery

See an example here: [Migrate hive table to Google BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46958916/migrate-hive-table-to-google-bigquery/47038501#47038501)

As mentioned above, take care about the types compatibility between Hive/Avro/BigQuery.

And for the first time I guess it would not hurt to do some validations by comparing that the tables on both Hive and BigQuery have the same data: https://github.com/bolcom/hive_compared_bq