# Whats the recommended way of copying data from hive table to Bigquery

Tags: hive, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, orc

I have seen 
[Move data from hive tables in Google Dataproc to BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47900265/move-data-from-hive-tables-in-google-dataproc-to-bigquery)
[Migrate hive table to Google BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46958916/migrate-hive-table-to-google-bigquery/47038501#47038501)

But issue with distcp is, it will move data from hdfs to gs..and My tables are in ORC format. Also till now bigquery is claiming to support only JSON, CSV, AVRO.

So need help to transfer data from hive table (ORC format) to BigQuery(any format)

Comment: You could add a comment [on the related feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73252292) asking to be whitelisted when it is available. Until then, your best option is probably just to convert to a supported format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Elliot, ORC is not supported. So you have to convert your ORC data into one of the 3 formats you mentioned.
I would personally prefer Avro because this serialization is more robust than JSON or CSV.

So the process to follow is:

1. Create your BQ table with the correct data types (need to be done as first step, to ensure proper cast with some Avro logical types like Timestamp)
2. Launch a Hive query to generate the data in a Avro format. See [this SQL example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46958916/migrate-hive-table-to-google-bigquery/47038501#comment81024969_47038501).
3. disctp to Google Cloud Storage
4. "bq load" into your table
5. Check that you haven't done any mistake  by comparing that the tables on both Hive and BigQuery have the same data: https://github.com/bolcom/hive_compared_bq

Comment: I've just updated my gcloud stack this morning and I've seen this note in the release notes:  "  BigQuery
      ▪ Added experimental support for import of ORC files into BigQuery." . So it seems to come earlier than I would have expected

Comment: This sounds promising.. Thankyou for your reply.

Comment: Consider upvoting / accepting this answer if it was helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

orc is supported and you can easily create table from GCP console.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-orc

I have done it .

NOTE : The schema of the table is never mentioned in the orc files in case of hive tables and hence while uploading you will get column names as below picture . Once table created you need to rename and update the column names.
[image]

[image]