# Transferring hive tables stored in orc format from on premise HDFS to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, google-cloud-storage, orc

I need to transfer very huge tables stored in an on premise HDFS to Google Cloud.All the tables are in ORC format. What is the best way to transfer all my tables?

Comment: According to what does distcp not support orc? It copies any file types last time I checked

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to take a look on the [Migrating HDFS Data from On-Premises to Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migration/hadoop/hadoop-gcp-migration-data) guide where you can find a detail explanation of the main aspects you need to consider when moving your data to GCP, as well as the [steps](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migration/hadoop/hadoop-gcp-migration-data#moving_your_data) required to perform the migration task. Additionally, you can review the [Working with GCP partners](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migration/hadoop/hadoop-gcp-migration-data#working_with_cloud_storage_partners) option in case require specialized assistance on your migration.

Comment: The link shared by you explains migrating data using DistCp. However, distcp does not support ORC format yet. So is there any other way to migrate the data stored in orc format?

Comment: You can [convert your ORC files to a supported format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46958916/migrate-hive-table-to-google-bigquery/47038501#comment81024969_47038501), such as Avro, JSON or CSV, in order to use the `DistCp` command; Otherwise, you can implement the `hadoop fs -get` and `hadoop fs -copyToLocal` commands to copy your HDFS files to the local file system and then use [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/) gsutil Tool to load them into GCS.

Comment: I recommend you may take a look the [Loading ORC Data from Google Cloud Storage
](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-orc) guide as well in case you want to load your files into BigQuery.